# Create custom template Wordpress - not responsive

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, responsive

I'm quite new to WP, and am trying to learn some HTML5/CSS/PHP while using it. Currently I'm having some troubles. 
I created a custom page (to have just a clean blank page without the header etc...) and I also created a Contact Form 7 that should be responsive.. 
However this doesn't work. When I load it on mobile, it does not adjust.

This is the code for the template page:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blank Page Header
*
*/
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<div id="logo2" align="center"><img src="http://adventoury.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/IMG_20160507_153704_HDR-Recoveredcropped2.jpg" width="100%" ></div>
<br>




<!-- page title, displayed in your browser bar -->
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>

<!-- add feeds, pingback and stuff-->
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body id="top">
<div class='container_wrap' id='main'>
<div class='container'>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS to make my from responsive

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) { 
    .column-half{
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Kind regards!

Comment: Please, provide the actual HTML source code of the website in a pastebin doc. I'm 80% sure that either the CSS isn't loaded, or there is a syntax error in the HTML's head.

If you provide us a link to the actual website, it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this code for template

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blank Page Header
*
*/
get_header();
?>

<div class='container_wrap' id='main'>
<div class='container'>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```